# What does "so take it" mean in this dialogue?

Tags: meaning-in-context

Teacher: Don't interrupt.  Who's teaching in this class, you or me?

Student: You are. You are the Teacher, **so take it**.

Teacher: Thank you.

Does it mean "so continue" or "so do it" ?

Comment: Could you [edit] your post to provide more details? What is the source of this dialogue? What was the surrounding context? And have you copied/transcribed it correctly? See [Details, Please](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/q/439/36187) and the [Contributor's Guide (Asking)](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4785/36187) for more tips and examples.

Comment: It could mean 'take the class' (where _take_ means _teach, lead the class_).

Comment: It sounds incredibly rude and therefore a little unbelievable. The context would help clear it up.

Answer (score 1):

I often here such phrase in a combination with “there”. For example:

> *I will get you started and you take it from there*

In this case the second person assumes the responsibility for something that is not mentioned.

Another example that I can remember is a case with a popular American band the Ramones. Sometimes Joey Ramona was making some speech on the stage and right before the song start he used to say “Take it Dee Dee”. And Dee Dee Ramona usually screamed something like “1, 2, 3, 4” and the ban would start playing. It happens around the 10th second on the video below:

https://youtu.be/VozqqacnXng

So it this case, I see it in the same way. Joey has said everything we wanted and then he “passed the word” to the band and invited them to start playing.

In your case, I believe that the student was again “passing the word back to his teacher”. The student interrupted the teacher and then passes the word back. To my mind, it looks like it is “so continue”. Although, the student sounds very rude too me, too.